# php array to javascript using json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, symfony

I have a php array $presentation, and I am trying to assign it to a JavasScript variable. when I use json_encode i got this value:

```
{"image":"\/ara\/web\/uploads\/images\/slide\/34.jpeg","sound":"\/ara\/web\/uploads\/images\/slide\/34.mpga","content":"sentence"}
```

you see the back and forward slashes?

and this gets worst when I try to assign the variable to a javascript one: I get this:

```
 &quot;books&quot;:[{&quot;image&quot;:&quot;\/ara\/web\/uploads\/images\/slide\/32.jpeg&quot;
```

and this is the code:

php:

```
$presentation_slide = json_encode($presentation_slides)
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    var presentation = {{ presentation_slides }}
</script>
```

I am using sumfony2

Comment: What code are you using to interpret that `{{ presentation_slides }}` into something useful?  Whatever it is, it's HTML-encoding your JSON.  (As for the escaped slashes, they shouldn't be a problem -- JS doesn't mind them.  It interprets `\/` as just `/`.)

Comment: here is The code: In the controller:  return $this->render('AUIBookaBundle:Book:show.html.twig', array('presentation_slides' => $this->preparePresentation($id) )));int the twig template:  <script>
    var presentation = {{ presentation_slides }}
</script &quot;image&quot;:&quot;ara/web/uploads/images/slide/32.jpeg&quot;

Comment: Try using `{{ presentation_slides|raw }}`.  It looks like that'll prevent the HTML-encoding, unless `preparePresentation` is doing the encoding itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES option:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$presentation = json_encode($presentation_slides, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1):

The json_encoding function has numerous flags that you can pass to it, which enable the function to parse particular character sets. The following call ought to solve the problems you are having

`json_encode($presentation_slides, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP );`

Answer (score 0):

```
$presentation = json_encode($presentation_slides, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```